# Bootstrap 5 Text Selection Color Classes

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <p class="bg-primary text-white">
            This is an example paragraph for text selection!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When the background color is set to `bg-primary` and the text color to `text-white` of the paragraph element, text selections by the mouse go unnoticed.

Are there any Bootstrap classes to change the text selection colors? How can we change text selection colors by Bootstrap way?

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in BS5 ways to do this, but you can easily create your own rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no Bootstrap classes to change the text selection colors. You'll have to add CSS manually.

See the snippet below.

```css
.bg-primary.text-white::selection {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p class="bg-primary text-white">
          This is an example paragraph for text selection!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```